# Looking for a 3.3V IR sensor

Tags: power-supply, low-power, proximity-sensor

I am currently using a SHARP [GP2YOA21 infrared distance measuring sensor](http://www.sharpsma.com/webfm_send/1208) which is 5.0V. I am looking for an alternative IR sensor that would work with 3.3V.

Our application involves wireless sensor network, energy harvesting, etc.

Does anyone know any alternative?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use an inexpensive boost regulator? Eg. http://www.torex.co.jp/english/products/dcdc_converters/data/XC9140.pdf (only an inductor + caps required)

Answer (score 1):

Vishay offers a series of fully integrated IR proximity sensors such as the [VCNL4000](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83798/vcnl4000.pdf) that operate from 2.5 Volts through 3.6 Volts. This particular part has an I2C interface. Other parts in the family have different interface options.

For something with a simpler pulse-width interface, consider Vishay [TSSP4P38](http://www.vishay.com/docs/82474/tssp4p38.pdf) and its smaller counterparts. These require a separate IR LED emitting at 38 KHz.

The mechanism used is different between the Sharp and Vishay devices. The Vishay part uses daylight-filtered reflected IR **intensity** to determine proximity, while the Sharp part uses **angular displacement** of IR signal reflected from the target. Thus, results may be different depending on the actual deployment scenario.